# How to enlarge the top panel in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, system-tray

In the top panel there are application icons - like in the Windows tray. And these icons are very small (compared to Windows). For example, it is very difficult for me to see the number of unread messages on the Telegram icon. How can I enlarge the top panel and icons on it? I have Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: I have no personal experience with it, so I can't tell how much it helps, if at all, but this gnome-shell-plugin gives you an alternative taskbar, that goes on the bottom of the screen: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/ Maybe it's somewhat bigger...

Comment: This seems to be how it's called in the Universe package: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/gnome-shell-extension-dash-to-panel So, using this name you could probably install it with the `apt install` command.

Comment: @Levente, thanks it helped me.

Comment: @Levente If you can, please post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to [@RandomPerson's suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1341888/how-to-enlarge-the-top-panel-in-ubuntu-20-04?noredirect=1#comment2297709_1341888), I transfer the gist of my comments into this answer, because [OP's feedback](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1341888/how-to-enlarge-the-top-panel-in-ubuntu-20-04?noredirect=1#comment2292907_1341888) ("thanks it helped me") makes it appear that they were useful.

---

> I have no personal experience with it, so I can't tell how much it helps, if at all, but the ["Dash to Panel" gnome-shell-extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/) gives you an alternative taskbar, that goes on the bottom of the screen. Maybe it's somewhat bigger...

> This seems to be how it's called in the Universe package: [gnome-shell-extension-dash-to-panel](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/gnome-shell-extension-dash-to-panel) So, using this name, you could probably install it with the `apt install` command.